# How to disable caching of 301 responses in an extension for specific domains

Tags: google-chrome-extension, http-status-code-301

I'm working on a Chrome extension that detects and redirects certain domains, but when the origin server sends a 301 redirect, the cached response interferes with detecting whether I should perform my own redirect on subsequent requests. I need the extension to prevent the browser from caching the redirect.

I've looked into the onHeadersReceived event, as this seems to be the first event that fires after we get the 301 response, but that event fires after caching directives are received, and won't prevent the response from being cached.

Comment: To clarify, I want to allow the redirect to happen when sent by the origin server, I just need to keep it from being cached. Essentially I want to make 301s behave like 302s.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having a hard time with a 301 redirect on your website never changing on your browser, even using the network -> Disable cache (while DevTools is open) with dev tools open. Try in DevTools to put in the console: `$.get(“https://redirect.url.com/page”)` which returned the post response as 200. Check this [blogpost](https://salferrarello.com/chrome-clear-redirect-cache/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, saw that post already. The issue though is that the origin server will continue to send the 301 (the redirect is legitimate if accessing the site directly), but my extension needs to do its own redirect to send the request through a reverse proxy, and the redirect is preventing me from detecting the session state on the proxy. The only reliable way I've found to detect whether I the user needs to authenticate to the proxy is if the initial request redirects them to the login page, and the cached 301 appears to the extension like an allowed request by the proxy.